# Pasar de Numero a Mes en Java

Tags: java, date, servlets

Estimado,

Tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar, estoy trabajando en un servlet donde obtengo un dato como int desde el web service, por lo que necesito pasar al mes correspondiente por ejemplo si es 1 que sea Enero...

Asi es como recibo el int del servicio...

```
int     mesdeTermino            =   listado_actividades.get(i).getMesTermino();
```

y estoy intenando con esto pasar el dato a fecha (SOLO NECESITO EL MES)

```
                Calendar calendarTermini = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendarInicio.setTime(mesdeTermino);
```

Comment: El problema es que le estás pasando el mes con  `setTime`, puedes probar algo así: `calendarInicio.set(Calendar.MONTH, mesdeTermino);`  OJO: los meses empiezan con `0: Enero, 1: Febrero` ... por tanto, si `mesdeTermino` no contempla ese detalle tendrás que sumarle `1` en el `set`, haciendo algo como: `calendarInicio.set(Calendar.MONTH, mesdeTermino+1);`

Comment: @A.Cedano y como lo imprimo ?? como calendarInicio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que estás aplicando `setTime` al objeto, cuando deberías aplicarle un simple `set`, indicando como primer parámetro que es un mes y como segundo parámetro el número de mes.

OJO, en `Calendar` los números de mes empiezan por `0=Enero, 1=Febrero, 2=Marzo ...` Debes tenerlo en cuenta si vas a trabajar con `Calendar`, porque posiblemente tengas que restar `1` al valor de la variable (ver **solución 2**).

Te propongo dos soluciones, según la versión de Java que estés usando:

### Solución 1: Java 8+

Si estás usando Java 8, puedes simplificar el proceso usando la [clase `Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/class-use/Month.html), que es parte del [nuevo paquete **`time`** de Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/paquete-java-time-2390472-esa.html).

Podrás crear con suma facilidad un objeto únicamente a partir del número de mes y mostrarlo en castellano.

El código sería algo así:

```
    int mesdeTermino = 3;
    Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
    Month mMonth=Month.of(mesdeTermino);
    String monthName=mMonth.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL,locale);  
    System.out.println(monthName);
```

**Salida:**

```
marzo
```

---

#### Solución 2: Java 8-

Puedes hacerlo mediante `Calendar`.

```
    int mesdeTermino = 3;
    Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
    Calendar calendarInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
    /*Restamos 1 a la variable por lo dicho al inicio*/
    calendarInicio.set(Calendar.MONTH, mesdeTermino-1);
    String monthName=calendarInicio.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, locale);
    System.out.println(monthName);
```

**Salida:**

```
marzo
```

Comment: Genial me ha funcionado, pero si quisiera ponerlo en Mayuscula ? donde deberia agregar el UPPER?

Comment: @JuanPablo tendrías que aplicarlo a la cadena de salida. Sea a la misma variable, por ejemplo: `String monthName=mMonth.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL,locale).toUpperCase();` en cuyo caso la variable se crea en mayúscula,  o bien al imprimir: `System.out.println(monthName.toUpperCase());`

Comment: muchas gracias!!